# Inclusion of SOAP entry in my Jersey 2 REST API

Tags: java, rest, soap, jersey, cxf

I am developing a REST API using Jersey 2 and apparently I need to process SOAP requests as well. How do I do that? How do I register a SOAP resource in my Jersey application?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean when you say "SOAP entry"? Do you mean you also need to be able to process SOAP requests?

Comment: Yes, I need to be able to process SOAP requests.

Comment: I made Apache CXF cxf-codegen-plugin create the interface from the WSDL file and I have implemented that interface. But that is not really sufficient ofc...

Comment: I have given up and am now keeping the SOAP stuff in a CXF project of it's own.